# Consider Array Elements One At A Time

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I am using [webmerge](https://www.webmerge.me) to create documents.

I have a rule that looks like this (ignore the `{$docType}` conditional for this question):

[image]

And I pass JSON data that looks like this:

```
{   
    "forms": [
        {
      "formID": 19,
      "formUrl": "https://www.webmerge.me/merge/123456/y3wpgu",
      "fillIns": {
        "retainedAmount": "2000000"
        }
      },
      {
      "formID": 20,
      "formUrl": "https://www.webmerge.me/merge/111111/a2X5yn",
      "fillIns": []
      }
   ]
 }
```

This works great and will load each form based on the URL provided as needed.

However, if I have two identical forms with differing `fillIns`, like this:

```
{   
    "forms": [
        {
      "formID": 19,
      "formUrl": "https://www.webmerge.me/merge/123456/y3wpgu",
      "fillIns": {
        "retainedAmount": "1000000"
                }
        },
      {
      "formID": 19,
      "formUrl": "https://www.webmerge.me/merge/123456/y3wpgu",
      "fillIns": {
        "retainedAmount": "2000000"
        }
      }
   ]
 }
```

It merges two forms as it should, but each form has both values for `retainedAmount`, based on the following mapping:

```
{foreach from=$forms item=_row}{if $_row.formID == 19}{if !empty($_row.fillIns.retainedAmount)}{$_row.fillIns.retainedAmount|number_format}{/if}{/if}{/foreach}
```

So the final result for both forms will look like this:

> **Retained Amount**: 10000002000000

The result I want is that the first instance of the form displays

> **Retained Amount**: 1000000

and the second displays

> **Retained Amount**: 2000000

It appears that since the mapping is looping through each element in the array every time, that is why each form is adding both values.

I have been playing with `array_shift` and `array_pop` so that the rule will repeat but only consider one element at a time, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

I think I need to get each element into a variable and then reference that variable in the map, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I would show all my attempts, but it will just be ugly, I think.

Lastly, I will never know at which index or how many identical forms with differing fillIns will appear, so I cannot use a key to guide me either.

Since I realize that not everyone has webmerge, a final result via print would be something like this:

```
FormID = 19 |Retained Amount = 1000000
FormID = 19 |Retained Amount = 2000000
```

Comment: just to clarify -> you want an array on dupe form IDs with two entries for the different values?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - The thing about your comment that is throwing me off is that "I want an array". I have the array already (see JSON), the array will have *n* elements, of which multiple could be the same formID, only with differing values in the fillIns (in the example, `retainedAmount` are different). I need a way to produce results so that each form only has one retainedAmount on it. In terms of "printing the final results to the screen", I would want to see: `formID = 19 | Retained Amount = 1000000 /n formID=19 | Retained Amount = 20000`

Comment: I see that I just mean a `final` array with desired results. So, will it always be the first instance of the duped field that will be the value? Anything else to go where? Display where? or do you mean like: `array(19 => array('retained_amount' => array(1000, 2000)))` for example?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs. I don't want a final result array. What I want is that the mapping of the value to the form considers only one element. The first time the array passes formID = 19 only use the fillIn from that element. The next time, only use the fillIn from that element. There may be some language barrier in my understanding here but I have a general idea of what I think *should* happen, but that my not be what is *able* to happen. That is why I was considering `array_shift` so that on each loop it only considers the first element in the array and thus only element at a time.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - And thanks for looking at this. My colleagues and I and even webmerge are very stumped on how to solve it.